# Embed YouTube video on Tumblr

Tags: youtube, tumblr, embed

I've been searching but what I've found was always about uploading a video to Tumblr or about adding audio only on Tumblr. None of the results has a solution for my problem. I just want to display a video that's already uploaded on YouTube, not uploading it to Tumblr. How do I embed YouTube video on a [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com) **text** post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you misinterpret what the user interface is saying.

[image: The first option is embed]

There are two options in the [video interface](http://www.tumblr.com/new/video).

1. Embed a video
2. Upload a video

You want option 1. If you want to add some text you can use the caption.

Another way to do this will be a regular "Add a Text" Post

[image: Add a Text Post]

From there you can use html and YouTube embed option (using the share link at the bottom of a YouTube video) to place it where ever you wish.

Example

```
<p>Go for text</p>
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IwX3FdwMCUs" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<p>And here goes the rest.</p>
```

Comment: Must I create a special post on tumblr just for the sake of embedding a video and then update my another **text** post to display the video? So my tumblr will have two posts (video and text) instead of one text post (which I want), no? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Arie It depends where you want the text. The "Add a video" post option allows some caption to be placed under it. Otherwise you can use the "Add a Text" post option.

Comment: awesome! it's working! thanks!!

Comment: I have been doing the same as you've told, but when I embed the video, it is shown in the editing area but after clicking update preview, I cant see the video I embeded, how come? thanks!